# «test.sh» нельзя открыть, так как Microsoft Excel не разрешено открывать документы в Терминале

Tags: excel, shell, vba

В общем пытаюсь запустить sh файл через ексель vba выдает такую ошибку
"«test.sh» нельзя открыть, так как Microsoft Excel не разрешено открывать документы в Терминале."
что только не делал по сто раз chmod + x путь   писал,
переместил файл в корневую папку excel,
менял формат на command,
переустанавливал office 3 разные версии пробовал,
ничего не помогает.
скрипт выглядит так

> PathFile = "/Applications/MicrosoftExcel.app/Contents/Resources/test.sh"
>
> Call Shell(PathFile, vbNormalFocus)

Comment: а почему он у вас sh, а не bat ?

Comment: попробовал
«cron.bat» нельзя открыть, так как Microsoft Excel не разрешено открывать документы в Терминале.

Comment: хм. видимо она хочет выполнимый файл. попробуйте `cmd.exe /c путь-к-файлу-bat`

Comment: я забыл упомянуть, что это mac , exe не прокатит

Comment: ну тогда становится ясно почему sh. Кто у вас там отвечает за обработку шелл-скриптов, bash какой нибудь или просто /bin/sh только там конечно не `/c` посмотрите нужны ли какие нибудь ключи что бы ваш шелл выполнял файл. И если mac сильно похож на unix может там достаточно что бы на файле были права на запуск, вы же сделали его запускаемым ?

Comment: #!/usr/bin/env bash 
запускаемым я так понимаю это прописывание комманды chmod +x ./имяфайла
я не знаю, что еще можно сделать с этим файлом
прикол в том что это все работало день назад, а на след день перестало

Comment: если есть возможность может поможете в скайпе, за помощь могу заплатить

Comment: Нашел выход установив iterm2 и открываю через него sh фалы, excel ни на что не ругается в итоге